# What's the equivalent to initWithNibName: on OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm creating a test application, trying to use MVC, for Mac.

I have created 5 nib files, each with different windows, and class files for each nib.

What do I do so that when you press a button on the MainMenu.xib, it opens a new view?

I've seen use of the `initWithNibName:`, for iOS, but can't find how this works on a Mac. Or am I going about this the wrong way? If so, how do you manage different views and classes in a Mac application with Xcode?

Comment: When you say "open a new view", do you mean "open a new window"?

Comment: like close the current nib and open another, and then switch back and forth

Comment: Do you mean... close the current window and open a new window, or just switch the content views inside? Nibs can represent either windows or views, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you mentioned "I have created 5 nib files, each with different windows, and class files for each nib." I'm assuming you have 5 different *windows* (not views) and want to open them on button press.

Each window nib file is controlled by a `NSWindowController`, which would be the C in MVC. To actually load a nib file (programmatically) you assign it a `NSWindowController`; the `NSWindowController` in OS X is comparable to the `UIViewController` on iPhone.

```
NSWindowController *controller = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"nib1"]
```

Then you can open/close the window the NSWindowController manages.

`[controller showWindow:nil]` to show the window

`[controller.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]` to make the window the key window.

You're probably intending to do something else though, which is to keep the same window but to switch the content view of that window. In that case you'd want nib files that contain views (and use NSViewControllers to load them), not windows (because having windows would be redundant).

But even if you stick with windows, to replace the contentView:

```
[currentWindow setContentView:[newWindowController.window contentView]];
```

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You should read ALL the documentation Apple has to offer on Windows, views, and applications.

- [Fundamentals](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW6)
- [Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Windows](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/WinPanel.html)

Comment: could you perhaps explain the difference between windows and views? so if i have 5 different nibs, how would i use this code to close the current nib and open another on button press? thanks v much for your help

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to do some of the research yourself, it'll be a good learning process. Once you understand the fundamentals this question should be no problem to solve.

Comment: thanks very much for such a great answer. i just can't get my head round this stuff, so i guess i'm just gonna have to read all the documentation :) thanks v much!

Comment: It might be nice to get a good book to walk you through everything, if not already, because documentation (especially Apple's) can be dense. Have fun, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A window in some sense is the "frame", i.e. it has the three colored buttons and a title, and nothing else. Each window has a content view, which is the main view of the window, and is responsible for displaying content, e.g. buttons, text, images. The content itself is usually implemented as a view, i.e. NSButton and NSTextField are all subclasses of NSView.

This part of the OSX View documentation might be helpful:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH4-SW13

in particular, have a look at figures 3-1 and 3-2.

I hope this helps a bit with understanding. Then, to do what you want to do, follow the steps detailed in Vervious answer.